# Delete all items in Recycle Bin using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, recycle-bin, office365apis

Is there a way to batch delete all items in the recycle bin on the client side in SharePoint Online?

I've tried using javascript:emptyItems() in the browser but this appears to time out after removing about 2k items.  I have 1.5 million items and growing and would like to empty all at once and have a quick and easy way to do this going forward.  Is there a way to do this using JSOM, CSOM or REST API?

I'm open to anything which doesn't involve central admin or server side access.  Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. First **Navigate to the recycle bin** page (e.g.,http://localhost/_layouts/recyclebin.aspx).
2. **Remove the address from address bar**, type
   “**javascript:emptyItems()**” (Remove the quotes) **Press Enter**.
3. It will be asked **if you really want to empty the recycle bin**. Click OK to empty
   it; click **Cancel to leave it alone**.

Comment: Just try this setting then no need to do any coding for that

Comment: This was the first thing I tried.  It just hangs after deleting a couple of thousand records.  I let it run overnight and no difference.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve by power-shell save below Code in ps1 dont Forget to change site url from code and Run through managment Shell

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

function Remove-SPSiteSecondStageRecycleBin() 
{

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite] $siteCollection = Get-SPSite "http://sp:2000/sites/test" -ErrorAction Stop


    $recycleQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinQuery;
    $recycleQuery.ItemState = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinItemState]::SecondStageRecycleBin;
    $recycleQuery.OrderBy = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinOrderBy]::Default;

    $recycledItems = $siteCollection.GetRecycleBinItems($recycleQuery);

    $count = $recycledItems.Count;

    for($i = 0; $i -lt $count; $i++)
    {
        $g = New-Object System.Guid($recycledItems[$i].ID);
        $recycledItems.Delete($g);
    }


    $siteCollection.Dispose()
}

Function Load-SharePoint-Powershell
{ 
    Write-Host "TEST"
    if ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )
    {    
          Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction Stop

    }

}


Load-SharePoint-Powershell
Remove-SPSiteSecondStageRecycleBin
```

Comment: I know very little about powershell.  Do you have to run this on the SharePoint server or can you execute it from any computer?

Comment: yes you can run any computer or server where sharepoint is installed 
Tool:"Sharepoint Management Shell Required"

Comment: From what I could find on this it looks like you need central admin access to run it, which unfortunately I don't have.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-the-SharePoint-Online-Management-Shell-environment-7b931221-63e2-45cc-9ebc-30e042f17e2c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Would be better to use `Get-SPOSite` and `Connect-SPOnline` instead

Comment: This won't work for SharePoint online but it's along the right lines. Have to recode using SPO cmdlets

Answer (score 0):

if your open to rest than use the following api

site collection level (second stage bin):

```
/_api/site/RecycleBin/deleteAll()
```

web level (first stage bin):

```
/_api/web/RecycleBin/deleteAll()
```

its a post method!

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj246426%28v%3doffice.15%29